# Javascript - Using a string to prototype functions

Tags: javascript

So I am a super JS noob, I am not even sure I am asking this question properly, but...

I am trying to dynamically create buttons, then set their onclick event listeners to one of a set of predetermined functions.  I want to be able to do this one of two ways, as follows:

```
var newInput = document.createElement('input');
newInput.parameters = "xyz";
document.getElementById("element").appendChild(newInput);
newInput.onclick = "funcsnip" + array[variable] + "()";
```

Or, alternatively,

```
var newInput = document.createElement('input');
newInput.parameters = "xyz";
document.getElementById("element").appendChild(newInput);
newInput.onclick = array[variable];
```

Where the array is stocked with "myFunction()" primitives.

I have no doubt there are a million things I "should" be doing, but I am happy with the majority of my code, I just want to know basically how to pass a string as a parameter for onclick, if that is possible.

Or, if it is not possible, another way to attach an onclick event to a dynamic input element.

Simpler and more elegant, the better.  Thank you!

Comment: A solution like `newInput.onclick = array[variable]`  should be preferred of one that uses something like this `"funcsnip" + array[variable] + "()"` (even if it won't work anyway in that case). A solution using a string that will be evaluated might break when you e.g. use a minifier later. But where do you get `variable` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a string to onclick listener. It should be a function. What you can do alternatively is to create a map of functions.

Let's say you have these functions available:

```
function oneFunc() { console.log('one');
function twoFunc() { console.log('two');
```

Then you can create a mapping:

```
var map = {
  one : oneFunc,
  two : twoFunc
};
```

So you can access `oneFunc` by calling `map.one` or `map["one"]`.

Now solving your problem is straightforward

```
var newInput = document.createElement('input');
var variable = "one";
// var variable = "two";
newInput.parameters = "xyz";
document.getElementById("element").appendChild(newInput);
// You pass an actual function, but using a string parameter.
newInput.onclick = map[variable];
```

When you click a button, you will see "one" in the console.

Comment: zaynetro that is PERFECT!  Exactly what I was looking for.  I have never heard of a map, but I will definitely be using that from now on.  Thank you SO MUCH I was pulling my hair out over this one!

Comment: map is just a variable which is object in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string for every button that represents a function, you can write

```
var functionCollection = {
  'stringOne': function() {
   ...
  }
}

...

newInput.onclick = functionCollection[myStringValue];
```

or you could create one handler function and invoke it with the string type through binding, e.g.

```
function clickHandler(stringValue) {
  switch (stringValue) {
    case 'stringOne':
      return someSpecialFunction();
    ...
  }
}

...

newInput.onclick = clickHandler.bind(this, myStringValue);
```

Comment: Why do you need binding here? `clickHandler(myStringValue)` as simple

Comment: `clickHandler(myStringValue)` invokes the function immediately, we want it to be run when the user clicks

Comment: `clickHandler.bind()` invokes the function immediately also, which is what we want in this case. We invoke `clickHandler` function and return `someSpecialFunction()` which is onclick listener function (will be run when user clicks)

Comment: `someSpecialFunction` is returned invoked, so if it returns a string we have a similar situation to what the poster wanted to avoid. However, if we just return `someSpecialFunction` rather than `someSpecialFunction()`, you are correct.

Comment: This has been immensely useful, btw.  I use .bind constantly for this script!

Answer (score 0):

Both newInput.**setAttribute**("onclick", "alert(1)") and newInput.setAttribute("onclick", "function() {alert(1) }" will work. Your code doesn't work because you're trying to set a function string on the onclick **property**, which expects a true function object.

Having said that, you really should use addEventListener, or an abstraction like jquery's on.